# Printing the wrong div

Tags: javascript, php

i have a code that prints a specifik DIV, i use PHP to get the list.

```
<?php
$hentgg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dansetimer WHERE dato = '$dato' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5") or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($hentgg)) {
while($visgg = mysql_fetch_array($hentgg)) {
?>

<div id="mydiv">
The div thats beeing printede
</div>


<div class="note">
Shows the user info
</div>

<?php
}
} else {
    echo "Fail - no lines";
}
?>
```

My problem is that if i have 2 lines in my list, it always print the first line's DIV, how can that be - i use the following Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function PrintElem(elem)
    {
        Popup($(elem).html());
    }

    function Popup(data) 
    {
        var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=50mm,width=80mm');
        mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Handskemager Dans</title>');
        mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://terminal.dance4fun.dk/medlem/mainbon.css" type="text/css" />');
        mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        mywindow.document.write(data);
        mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

        mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
        mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

        mywindow.print();
        mywindow.close();
        popupWindow.hide ();

        return true;
    }

</script>
```

Normally i hide the div, so it's only being printed, but if i choose the show the div, it looks right (see picture below)

[image]

But as soon as i print, it prints the first div for USER A.

Comment: Ids must be unique, your code appears to create multiple elements with `id="mydiv"`

Comment: you should use a class="mydiv" and change your selector #mydiv to .mydiv

Comment: How can give them id's? Or where do i change my selector?

Comment: Use the 'dansetimer' table unique id as an id for the dom id's

Comment: but if i make it: mydiv2 for example, how will the javascript recognize it when it's just var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=50mm,width=80mm'); ? Can i in any way get the it up in the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

I must have been very tired ;-)

But the answer was of course to make:

```
<div class="mydiv<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

And of course on the button

```
<a href="#"  onclick="PrintElem('.mydiv<?php echo $id; ?>')" />
```

Thank you for your support guys.